# Fragment layout in place of headerLayout in NavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have implemented the layout instead of normal menu layout and header layout.
The problem is that the click listener of Fragment layout is not working. When i click on any Buton or Swtich, drawer gets close and the action not performed. I search and tried some solutions but does not worked...
Please look and review at the code and provide some assistance regarding this

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_260sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_side_drawer" />
```

and the layout_side_drawer is

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:name="com.hk.statusaver.fragment.SettingsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:text="@string/general"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivNotification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_notification" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNotification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivNotification"
            android:text="@string/auto_notification"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switchNotification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_14sdp"
            android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
            app:thumbTextPadding="@dimen/_8sdp"
            app:track="@drawable/switch_track" />
    </RelativeLayout>


SettingFragment code:
```

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    lateinit var edit: SharedPreferences.Editor
 //   private lateinit var binding: SettingsFragmentBinding
 public override fun onCreateView(
     inflater: LayoutInflater,
     container: ViewGroup?,
     savedInstanceState: Bundle?
 ): View? {
     val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_fragment, container, false)

    val d = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivDirect)
     d.setOnClickListener {
         Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "333333333333", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     }
     return view
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing with your NavigationView is because you're using a custom layout for the header, and the click listeners for the elements in your custom header layout are not working as expected. To make your click listeners work, you should set the click listeners in the fragment that corresponds to the custom header layout. In your case, it seems that you want to add click listeners to views inside the SettingsFragment.

```
class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    lateinit var edit: SharedPreferences.Editor

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_fragment, container, false)

        val d = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivDirect)
        d.setOnClickListener {
            // Handle the click event for the ImageView
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "ImageView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        val switchNotification = view.findViewById<SwitchCompat>(R.id.switchNotification)
        switchNotification.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            // Handle the switch state change event
            if (isChecked) {
                // Switch is turned on
            } else {
                // Switch is turned off
            }
        }

        // You can add click listeners for other views as needed.

        return view
    }
}
```

In the code above, we set up click listeners for the ImageView and the SwitchCompat inside the SettingsFragment. When the ImageView or the SwitchCompat is clicked or its state is changed, the corresponding click listener will be invoked, and you can handle the click events or state changes there.